# ReactJs Checkbox value and date not getting updated in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS, have tried to get the value of the checked/selected checkbox and also date selection from the input type date. but could not able to achieve.

When I click on `Generate Report` button, you can see the console displaying the states. only the location is getting saved, not the other option.

Here are my functions to update the state values and initial state values:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      selectedLocation: locationList[0].value,
      selectedServiceType: [],
      selectedStDate:new Date(1446887898),
      selectedEdDate:new Date(1446887898)
    };
  },
  selectServiceType:function(e){
    selectedTypes.indexOf(e.target.value)? selectedTypes.push(e.target.value):console.log('Already exists in array');
        this.setState({
      selectedServiceType: e.target.checked
    })

  },
  changeHandler: function(e) {
    this.setState({
      selectedLocation: e.target.value
    })
  },
  selectStDate: function(e) {
    this.setState({
      selectedDate: e.target.value
    })
  },
  selectEdDate: function(e) {
    this.setState({
      selectedEdDate: e.target.value
    })
  },
```

The complete Demo here 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d10xyqu1/28/)

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done refactoring, you can check it, [`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/d10xyqu1/30/)

```
var FulfilmentReport = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      services: this.props.services,
      location: this.props.locations[1].value,
      startDate: this.formatDate(new Date(1446887898)),
      endDate: this.formatDate(new Date(1446887898))
    };
  },

  changeService: function (e) {
    var services = this.state.services.map(function (service) {
      service.checked = (service.value === e.target.value) ? !service.checked : service.checked; 
      return service;
    });

    this.setState({
      services: services
    });
  },

  handleChange: function(field, e) {
    var data = {};
    data[field] = e.target.value;

    this.setState(data);
  },

  render: function() {
    var buttonClasess = [
      'right', 'mdl-button', 'mdl-js-button', 'mdl-button--raised',
      'mdl-js-ripple-effect', 'mdl-button--colored'
    ].join(' ');

    var services = this.state.services.map(function (service) {
      return [
        <label>{ service.name }</label>,
        <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          name={service.value}  
          value={service.value}
          checked={service.checked}
          onChange={ this.changeService } />
        ];
    }, this)

    var locations = this.props.locations.map(function (location, index) {
      return (<option key={index} value={ location.value }>{ location.name }</option>);
    });

    var elements = [{
      label: <label>Location</label>,
      data: <select 
              onChange={ this.handleChange.bind(this, 'location') } 
              value={ this.state.location }>{ locations }</select>
    }, {
      label: <label>Service Type</label>,
      data: <div>{ services }</div>
    },{
      label: <label>Start Date</label>,
       data: <input 
              type="date" 
              value={ this.state.startDate } 
              onChange={ this.handleChange.bind(this, 'startDate') } />
    },{
      label: <label>'End Date'</label>,
      data: <input 
              type="date" 
              value={ this.state.endDate } 
              onChange={ this.handleChange.bind(this, 'endDate') } />
    }];

    elements = elements.map(function (element) {
      return [element.label, element.data];
    });

    return (<div id="items">
      <div>{ elements }</div>
      <input type="button" value="Generate Report" onClick={ this.onItemClick } className={ buttonClasess } />
    </div>);
  },

  onItemClick: function() {
    this.state.services = this.state.services.filter(function (el) {
      return el.checked;
    }) ;

    console.log( this.state );
  },

  formatDate: function (date) {
    return date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
  }
});
```